# how can I find out whether and where some identity under a given namespace is used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In an C# cs file opened under Visual Studio 2015, how can I find out whether and where some identity under a given namespace is used, when the namespace is declared at the beginning with `using`?

For example, with

```
using System.Linq
```

how can I find out whether something defined in `System.Linq` is ever used in the file? If yes, where it is used in the file? 
If no, I will remove the `using System.Linq` statement. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Visual Studios are you using? In VS 2017 the unused usings are automatically highlighted and the Quick Actions has the option to remove them all.

Answer (score 2):

As listed in [MSDN's Removing Unused Usings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514115(v=vs.120).aspx):

The **Remove Unused Usings** option in the Visual Studio user interface removes **using** directives, **using** aliases, and **extern** aliases that are not used in the source code. There are two ways to call the operation:

1. Main Menu - On the **Edit** menu, point to **IntelliSense**, point to **Organize Usings**, and then click **Remove Unused Usings**.
2. Context Menu - Right-click anywhere inside the code editor, point to **Organize Usings**, and then click **Remove Unused Usings**.

---

**Note**

If you perform **Remove Unused Usings** on source code that does not build, some required **using** directives may be removed.

Comment: Thanks. When it is used, how can i find out where the identities defined in it is used in the file?

Comment: @Tim - One simple case is to comment out that `using` line, and check where all the compile-time errors have shown! This way you can determine the usage of that using statement. For those usings which have not been used, it shows that using statement as dull and kind-of disabled.

Comment: @Tim - You may like to accept the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to accept an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

A quick way would be to just remove the using statement, and try to compile, and see if you get any errors about missing types.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: right click, Organize Usings -> Remove Unnecessary Usings.
Ha, beaten to it by I_Am_Helpful.  Yes, you are.